# What is "Radan HTTP"?

Tags: linux, service, port

There is a service using the 8088 port on a Linux server I use. It identifies itself as radan-http, and indeed it's on the [IANA port list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt). It is apparently being used by Nginx.

But, despite a fair amount of searching, I haven't been able to find out what it is. Is there documentation for it and what it does somewhere?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The port itself (8088) was originally registered to Radan for vendor-specific HTTP traffic. It has since been co-opted by the general public for use for proxies (along with 8000, 8080, 8888).

I have a feeling it's not Nginx identifying itself as Radan, but that the software you are using to scan is just referencing the IANA port list.

Comment: This seems right, but I think it's probably not scanning software, just `netstat`, which reads from `/etc/services`, which uses names from the IANA list linked to in the question.

Comment: @mattdm true, that's also a possibility. I guess one could somehow find a linguistic/technical way to argue that `netstat` is some branch variety of 'scanning software' ;-)