# What is this strange nginx running on 8088?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, port-scanning

I recently made a nmap scan to my server, and I discovered that there was some strange instance of nginx running on port 8088.

```
8088/tcp  open     http         nginx 1.0.11
| http-methods: 
|_  Supported Methods: GET HEAD
|_http-server-header: nginx/1.0.11
|_http-title: Welcome to nginx!
```

I visited the page and is just the default nginx page (not the same I have on my main nginx instance on port 80)
[The weird instance on port 8088](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwgby.png)

But this is my normal nginx placeholder on port 80:
[Normal nginx placeholder running on port 80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imK1t.png)
I noticed that nginx -v shows:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
```

But as seen earlier, according to nmap, 8088 is running 1.0.11 not 1.10.0
A quick *netstat -tulpn | grep :8088* returned:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8088            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19003/nginx
```

I didn't find any mention to the port 8088 on the entire /etc/nginx (Yes, I checked everything). 
I don't want to kill the process until I know what it is, any ideas?

I found something similar [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/398462/what-is-radan-http) (on server fault).

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to narrow the search to only one user.
The instance was a remain of the recently deleted `phoronix-test-suite`.

I just killed the process and it never came again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ps` to get more information about the process you've found using `netstat` with something like

```
ps ef --pid 19003 | cat
```

In your case `nginx` could be running because a different user or program launched it "manually" or because the configuration was changed, that's why `ps` could give you more information.

Comment: Ouch, it looks like you already found the culprit. But using `ps` with `netstat` (or `ss`) is still a good idea for future searchers :)